# FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::JSON::EncodeError: Invalid UTF-8 string: cannot encode to UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, chef-infra

While installing chef-server on my VM I am getting the following error.

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::JSON::EncodeError: Invalid UTF-8 string: cannot encode to UTF-8
```

and my chef-stacktrace.out is

```
Chef::Exceptions::JSON::EncodeError: Invalid UTF-8 string: cannot encode to UTF-8
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/json_compat.rb:107:in `rescue in to_json'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/json_compat.rb:104:in `to_json'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/http/json_input.rb:35:in `handle_request'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/http.rb:222:in `block in apply_request_middleware'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/http.rb:220:in `each'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/http.rb:220:in `inject'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/http.rb:220:in `apply_request_middleware'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/http.rb:141:in `request'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/http.rb:118:in `put'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/node.rb:512:in `save'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/client.rb:257:in `save_updated_node'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/client.rb:403:in `run'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/application.rb:243:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/application.rb:220:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:38:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/application.rb:201:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/application/client.rb:328:in `run_application'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/application.rb:58:in `run'
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/opscode/embedded/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
/opt/opscode/embedded/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
~
~
~
```

I have tried almost everything. I realised that the issue was related to encoding but couldn't solve it. Any help is appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: What is the locale of your node, which distribution? Try with `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 chef-client` to see if this solve the problem.

Comment: @Tensibai I am just trying to setup the server. I have set LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 earlier. But it didn't work.

Comment: @Tensibai distribution is ubuntu 12.04. I set all my locale variables to en_US.UTF-8

Comment: So there's probably something in the node object which does not comply to UTF-8, a user name or another attribute somewhere...

Comment: I'm getting this error too.   Some additional information: I'm running chef on Ubunutu 16.04 on an AWS EC2 instance.   I installed chef 12.3.0 using `apt install chef`.   I get this error running `chef-client --local-mode hello.rb` with the simple hello world MOTD recipe from https://learn.chef.io/modules/learn-the-basics/ubuntu/aws/configure-a-resource#/   My stack trace is nearly identical to the one above.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should be fixed in version `12.4.0`

https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/3216